# React JS, Router - component renders only after clicking a link

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I wondering how to resolve problem with component rendering... Imagine situation:

I have 4 boxes on page, and clicking each box causes redirect to another page.

Each box has different data I'm passing like this:

```
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: '/someurl/' + sometitle + '/' + someid,
            state: {
              title,
              description,
              purpose}}} > 
               <div></div> 
         </Link>
```

After clicking each box, everything goes ok - I receive page with data depending on which box I have clicked. Example url looks like this localhost/someurl/sometitle1/someid1.

The problem is when I'm trying to go this link directly from search bar... Of course I know why - all data is passing with clicking the box, so if there is no click, there are no data...

I just don't know how to resolve this :/

Any ideas?

Comment: Have a read about server side rendering

Answer (score 0):

In order to implement a solution whereby on going to a link on a page you are able to display the data directly to it, you must make sure that all information related to the page is already in the url or is derivable from the url

For instance you can ignore sending data as state to the RouteComponent but fetch the data based on urlParams, someTitle and someId.

Assuming your Route is configured like

```
<Route path="/someurl/:title/:id" component={Component}/>
```

You can write your Component like

```
const Component = ({match}) => {
   const {title, id} = match;
   const [data, setData] = useState({});
   useEffect(() => {
       // fetchData based on title and id and update state
   }, [title, id]);
   ...
}
```

P.S. If you do not use hooks, you can convert eh above useEffect and useState logic to state and componentDidUpdate/componentDidMount lifecycle functions for class component